# Reprogram behavior of media/f-keys for Lenovo Yoga 900

Tags: lenovo-laptop, hotkeys, function-keys

Is it possible to modify the behavior of individual f-key buttons?

For instance, the Yoga 900 doesn't have any play / next / media buttons. 
I'd much prefer to have some f-keys behave like that instead of the existing ones, like f4, which closes the window (wtf?), and airplane mode... (both dangerous!).

It would be nice to customize the behavior of f--keys individually.

Comment: i'm probably not going to buy lenovo in  the future, for this reason.

also, their software layer for windows seems quite buggy. Bugs include my two finger scrolling stops working for random reasons, layout doesn't remember when switching from desktop mode to tablet mode to desktop mode (could be a windows thing, not lenovo). trackpad having a delay before responding, despite setting the delay to 0.